# Default attribute list should come to my class definition in c# .net

Tags: .net, attributes, propertydescriptor

I have a employee class:

```
public class Employee
{

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Int32 Salary { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

and I have created a custom Attribute `CustomeAttribute` as

```
public class CustomAttributes : Attribute
{

        public  int Sequence {set;get;}
        public  int Length { set; get; }

}
```

I am using `CustomAttribute` as attribute in `Employee` as

```
public class Employee
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
} 

public class Employee
{

    [CustomAttributes(Sequence=1,Length=10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [CustomAttributes(Sequence = 2, Length= 6)]
    public Int32 Salary { get; set; }
    [CustomAttributes(Sequence =3, Length = 8)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I want to validate attribute collection should be there for each property definition.
If I add new property `Age` to ´Employee` as

```
public class Employee 
{
    [CustomAttributes(Sequence=1,Length=10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [CustomAttributes(Sequence = 2, Length= 6)]
    public Int32 Salary { get; set; }
    [CustomAttributes(Sequence =3, Length = 8)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

I should get compile time error as attributes are missing. Which will ensure writing 
Attribute values to each of property of a that class as well to a class which is from same assembly.??

I should get compile time error for a property without attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of generating a compile-time error for this. However, you could do something with reflection, in either your unit tests or the `#debug` build - simply iterate over the properties, checking `Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(CustomAttributes))`